# With r programming, how do I select a particular amount of outputs in a sample?

Tags: r

For example, If I flip 100 coins, what is the probability that exactly 50 lands on heads?  I tried messing with length() and sum() but I didn't get the the correct answer (unless I did it wrong).

My code:

```
flips <- function(){
  
coins <- sample(c("H","T"), 100, replace = T)
  

  
}

mean(replicate(10000, flips() == "H"))
```

Comment: `dbinom(50, 100, 0.5)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there. Return the output of `sample` or don't assign it to `coins`. So you get 100 coin flips.

```
flips <- function(){
  sample(c("H","T"), 100, replace = T)
}
flips()

#  [1] "H" "H" "T" "H" "H" "T" "T" "T" "H" "H" "H" "T" "H" "T" "T" "H" "H" "H" "T" "T"
# [21] "T" "T" "H" "T" "H" "T" "T" "T" "H" "H" "T" "T" "T" "H" "T" "T" "T" "H" "H" "T"
# [41] "T" "H" "T" "T" "H" "H" "T" "H" "T" "H" "T" "T" "H" "T" "H" "H" "H" "H" "T" "T"
# [61] "H" "H" "H" "H" "H" "H" "T" "H" "T" "T" "H" "T" "T" "H" "T" "H" "T" "T" "H" "T"
# [81] "T" "T" "H" "H" "T" "H" "H" "H" "T" "T" "T" "H" "H" "H" "H" "T" "H" "T" "H" "H"
```

Now `replicate` it 1000 times.

```
mean(replicate(10000, flips() == "H"))
#[1] 0.501199
```

To calculate probability that exactly 50 of them land on head can be calculated as :

```
set.seed(123)
mean(replicate(10000, sum(flips() == "H") == 50))
#[1] 0.0796
```

Comment: That isnt my main issue, how would I find the probability that exactly 50 out of the 100 coins will land on heads?

Comment: ohhh so it was sum.  I guess my placement was wrong for when I was messing with it.  Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Using `rerun`

```
library(purrr)
mean(rerun(10000,  sample(c("H","T"), 100, replace = TRUE) == "H"))
```